# Django unit tests with custom table names

Tags: django, unit-testing

Has anyone successfully used Django unit tests with custom table names? If so, were there any special hoops you had to jump through in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has anyone successfully used Django unit tests with custom table names?

Yes. I have.

> If so, were there any special hoops you had to jump through in order to get it to work?

No.

Whats your real question? If you put the real table name in the model under 'Meta', django creates tables in corresponding names.

Comment: The question I asked is my real question. I separately asked another, more specific question elsewhere but people seemed to have trouble separating the forest from the trees, so I asked a more general one. My specific issue is that Django is complaining that my `customer` table doesn't exist in the test database, so apparently Django is not creating that table for some reason. I'm putting the real table name under `Meta`.